# How do I use SendGrid's Inbound Parse Webhook example in Postman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, postman, griddler

I am trying to figure out why incoming emails have paragraphs stripped in my Ruby on Rails app with [Griddler](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler) and SendGrid. To do that I'd like to mock an inbound email using Postman.

SendGrid have [an example 'Default Payload'](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Inbound_Parse_Webhook/setting_up_the_inbound_parse_webhook.html) which looks like this:

```
[Date] array(16) {
  ["headers"]=>
  string(1970) "Received: by mx0047p1mdw1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id 6WCVv7KAWn Wed, 27 Jul 2016 20:53:06 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from mail-io0-f169.google.com (mail-io0-f169.google.com [209.85.223.169]) by mx0047p1mdw1.sendgrid.net (Postfix) with ESMTPS id AA9FFA817F2 for <parse@parse.yourdomain.com>; Wed, 27 Jul 2016 20:53:06 +0000 (UTC)
Received: by mail-io0-f169.google.com with SMTP id b62so81593819iod.3 for <parse@parse.yourdomain.com>; Wed, 27 Jul 2016 13:53:06 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=sendgrid.com; s=ga1; h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to; bh=DpB1CYYeumytcPF3q0Upvx3Sq/oF4ZblEwnuVzFwqGI=; b=GH5YTxjt6r4HoTa+94w6ZGQszFQSgegF+Jlv69YV76OLycJI4Gxdwfh6Wlqfez5yID 5dsWuqaVJZQyMq/Dy/c2gHSqVo60BKG56YrynYeSrMPy8abE/6/muPilYxDoPoEyIr/c UXH5rhOKjmJ7nICKu1o99Tfl0cXyCskE7ERW0=
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=1e100.net; s=20130820; h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to; bh=DpB1CYYeumytcPF3q0Upvx3Sq/oF4ZblEwnuVzFwqGI=; b=Sq6LVHbmywBdt3sTBn19U8VOmelfoJltz8IcnvcETZsYwk96RBxN+RKMN5fOZSKw4j 15HrgdIFfyDmp67YK0ygvOITlTvZ6XY5I0PtnvDtAQt79kS3tKjI3QKJoEp/ZjIjSzlL KG7agl6cxFgBbIN0yHWBOvy3O+ZXY8tZdom1yOvULjmjW1U9JkdOs+aJ6zq4qhZX/RM/ tIgLB461eJ5V95iQDDc5Ibj9Cvy4vJfXLQRO0nLVQAT2Yz58tkEO1bDZpWOPAyUNneIL yhIWp+SpbuqhMA68mq0krG1PjmWalUbpVcGJIGuOKB9mQFFo/MqdrUCjvYnyo1jPLPeX psdQ==
X-Gm-Message-State: AEkoousvdxmDoxLlTUYJ1AOmCGJv77xRBBlfKv6YrthH0M2NueMwlOxUD6t8nidE9uonXbdJ/DQy/chmHUnN//a4
X-Received: by 10.107.6.101 with SMTP id 98mr38024553iog.41.1469652785829; Wed, 27 Jul 2016 13:53:05 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.107.48.17 with HTTP; Wed, 27 Jul 2016 13:53:05 -0700 (PDT)
From: Sender Name <example@example.com>
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2016 14:53:05 -0600
Message-ID: <CAN_P_JMvV7ZpAQhOnDienypLrJmuhN=LQWweu4yScw4jQyXY2w@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Different File Types
To: parse@parse.yourdomain.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=001a113f8ad03e85160538a4343c
"
  ["dkim"]=>
  string(22) "{@sendgrid.com : pass}"
  ["content-ids"]=>
  string(37) "{"ii_1562e2169c132d83":"attachment1"}"
  ["to"]=>
  string(26) "parse@parse.yourdomain.com"
  ["html"]=>
  string(479) "<div dir="ltr">Here's an email with multiple attachments<div><br></div><div><img src="cid:ii_1562e2169c132d83" alt="Inline image 1" width="455" height="544"><br clear="all"><div><br></div>-- <br><div class="gmail_signature" data-smartmail="gmail_signature"><div dir="ltr"><img src="https://sendgrid.com/brand/sg-logo-email.png" width="96" height="17"><br><div><br></div></div></div>
</div></div>
"
  ["from"]=>
  string(33) "Sender Name <example@example.com>"
  ["text"]=>
  string(139) "Here's an email with multiple attachments
"
  ["sender_ip"]=>
  string(14) "209.85.223.169"
  ["spam_report"]=>
  string(844) "Spam detection software, running on the system "mx0047p1mdw1.sendgrid.net", has
identified this incoming email as possible spam.  The original message
has been attached to this so you can view it (if it isn't spam) or label
similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
@@CONTACT_ADDRESS@@ for details.

Content preview:  Here's an email with multiple attachments [image: Inline image
   1] -- [...]

Content analysis details:   (2.6 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
 0.8 HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_02    BODY: HTML has a low ratio of text to image area
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
 1.8 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_08     BODY: HTML: images with 400-800 bytes of words
 0.0 T_MIME_NO_TEXT         No text body parts

"
  ["envelope"]=>
  string(66) "{"to":["parse@parse.yourdomain.com"],"from":"example@example.com"}"
  ["attachments"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["subject"]=>
  string(20) "Different File Types"
  ["spam_score"]=>
  string(5) "2.597"
  ["attachment-info"]=>
  string(287) "{"attachment2":{"filename":"DockMcWordface.docx","name":"DockMcWordface.docx","type":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},"attachment1":{"filename":"MG_2359.jpg","name":"_MG_2359.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","content-id":"ii_1562e2169c132d83"}}"
  ["charsets"]=>
  string(77) "{"to":"UTF-8","html":"UTF-8","subject":"UTF-8","from":"UTF-8","text":"UTF-8"}"
  ["SPF"]=>
  string(4) "pass"
}
```

My problem is I don't really understand how to put this format into Postman as Postman has no way to specify a raw payload like this. Alternatively, could I use curl to achieve something similar?

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring this out yet?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to test a azure function app locally and managed to mock a request

1. create a request bin at https://requestbin.com
2. On sendgrid inbound api page, add a host/url to redirect to the created request bin
3. send a test mail to the test email adress
4. Go back to the request bin page, copy everything you see under "RAW BODY".
5. Paste the raw body in the Postman request body
   [image]
6. To get it to work, I also copied some of the headers to Postman, mainly the "Content-type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY"
   [image]